# Multi-threaded Exchange Online With Powershell Core - C#

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, exchange-server, powershell-core

I'm writing a C# application that will involve collecting data from Exchange Online using the [PowerShell V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps). After clients perform an admin consent, I will make PowerShell connections to their environments using a multi-threaded C# app running on a Windows virtual machine.  I'm using Net 5.0 and PowerShell 7.x. I need to use multiple threads because collecting data from a single tenant can be a lengthy process.

The problem is that while the app runs fine, if I try to run the application for two tenants at the same time using multiple threads, there is collision.  The module does not appear to be thread-safe.

I've built a service that gets injected via .Net DI as a transient.  This service creates a HostedRunspace class that performs state management for PowerShell.

```
public class HostedRunspace : IDisposable
{
    private Runspace runspace;
 
    public void Initialize(string[] modulesToLoad = null)
    {

        InitialSessionState defaultSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        defaultSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned;
        
        if (modulesToLoad != null)
        {
            foreach (string moduleName in modulesToLoad)
            {
                defaultSessionState.ImportPSModule(moduleName);
            }
        }

        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(defaultSessionState);
        
        runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseNewThread;
        runspace.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;

        runspace.Open();
    }

    public async Task<List<PSObject>> RunScript(string scriptContents, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters = null)
    {
        if (runspace == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Runspace must be initialized before calling RunScript().");
        }

        PSDataCollection<PSObject> pipelineObjects;
        
        using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create(runspace))
        {
            ps.AddScript(scriptContents);

            if (scriptParameters != null)
            {
                ps.AddParameters(scriptParameters);
            }

            ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
            ps.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += Warning_DataAdded;
            ps.Streams.Information.DataAdded += Information_DataAdded;

            // execute the script and await the result.
            pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("----- Pipeline Output below this point -----");
            foreach (PSObject item in pipelineObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
        }

        List<PSObject> psObjects = new List<PSObject>();
        foreach (PSObject pipelineObject in pipelineObjects)
        {
            psObjects.Add(pipelineObject);
        }

        return psObjects;
    }
```

When it becomes time to collect a tenant's PowerShell data, a new thread is created like so:

```
IOnlineDataTaskRunner taskRunner = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOnlineDataTaskRunner>();
Thread thread = new Thread(() => taskRunner.RunAsync(dataTask));
thread.Start();
```

Here I'm getting a transient version of my PowerShell service, which will itself new up a HostedRunspace.  I create a new thread, provide it some configuration and start the thread.

When the thread runs, I first must connect to Exchange Online which I do using a certificate.

```
string command = $"Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbprint \"{Thumbprint}\" -AppId \"{ClientId}\" -ShowBanner:$false -Organization {tenant}"; 
await runspace.RunScript(command);
```

Then, after this, I perform a variety of other data retrieval tasks using the PowerShell Module, including retrieving mailbox information, storage size, etc.  These are also executed via

```
await runspace.RunScript(command);
```

As stated above, if I run one thread at a time, there is no issue.  But if I connect thread 1 to tenant A and thread 2 to tenant B, the initial Connect-ExchangeOnline will take place with no issues.

But then if you retrieve mailbox information, for example, both threads will pull data for whichever tenant connected last.  This indicates that there may be a threading issue with the module or perhaps with my implementation.

Comment: Is there a reason you are running a powershell script from C#?  Why not just implement the powershell in C#, then you don't have the problem?

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure I understand your question.  What do you mean by "implement the PowerShell in C#"?.  I've referenced the Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK nuget and am using it to run PowerShell Core, which I believe is the way to run PowerShell in .net core apps.  

There are no other Exchange Online APIs that I could use as an alternative for this.

Comment: Is there a need to use C#? you can use runspaces as well as ThreadJob module for multithreading and wouldn't have this issue using just PowerShell

Comment: I might be wrong, but aren't the PS libraries, just wrappers around REST calls?  In which case, just make REST calls from C#

Comment: @Neil the REST calls are not documented.  I wish they were, since I loathe PowerShell, obviously.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon after the data is retrieved it needs to be groomed and then inserted into SQL databases, which is done via C#.  I think there must be a way for this process to work using C#.

Comment: Just to be sure, each threads uses its own `HostedRunspace` instance ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a second Tenant, but I do have a second user account with different permissions so that's what I'll use in my suggestions. I tested a couple ways of handling multiple exo connections, and here's what worked:

Using Powershell jobs via `Start-Job`. Jobs take place in their own sessions and have some level of isolation:

```
Start-Job -Name admin01 -ScriptBlock {
    Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin01@domain.com
    # Sleep so that second connection happens before this Get-Mailbox
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10; 
    Get-Mailbox user02@domain.com  ## should succeed as admin
}
Start-Job -Name user01  -ScriptBlock {
    Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName user01@domain.com
    Get-Mailbox user02@domain.com  ## should error due to access as user
}

Receive-Job -Name admin01  ## returns mailbox
Receive-Job -Name user01   ## returns error
```

It looks like `Connect-ExchangeOnline` uses `PSSession` objects to store your connection, which you can re-import to verify you are connected to the correct tenant e.g.:

```
Get-PSSession | ft -AutoSize

Id Name                            ComputerName          ComputerType  State  ConfigurationName  Availability
-- ----                            ------------          ------------  -----  -----------------  ------------
 5 ExchangeOnlineInternalSession_1 outlook.office365.com RemoteMachine Opened Microsoft.Exchange    Available
 6 ExchangeOnlineInternalSession_2 outlook.office365.com RemoteMachine Opened Microsoft.Exchange    Available
```

So I was able to use `Import-PSSession` to load a specific connection for a command:

```
# First, run as admin01
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin01@domain.com
Get-Mailbox user02@domain.com  ## Success

# Then, run as user01
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName user01@domain.com
Get-Mailbox user02@domain.com  ## Error

# Then, run as admin01 again:
Import-PSSession (Get-PSSession 5) -AllowClobber
Get-Mailbox user02@domain.com  ## Success
```

Finally, just running two separate powershell instances works as well.

I'm not very familiar with .net, but my guess is you're currently either re-using the `SessionState` when starting a new thread, or you're sharing your `runspace` across threads.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. I was hoping for a more C#-centric solution, but your answer gives me a framework that I can use to solve my problem. I'm awarding you the Accepted Answer.  Plus, your answer was also very well-written with relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure, but you can try the following:

Do a `Task.Run` and create the reference to `InitialSessionState` there.

The reason behind this (speculation ahead!): the `InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()` method is static, but not thread static ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate.createdefault?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)). Which could mean that you only create one `InitialSessionState` and share it among all the instances of your async `Task`s (remember that an async `Task` is not necessarily a new `Thread`). Which means that the same `InitialSessionState` is shared between your tasks. Thus resulting in logging on with one client and then the next. This could explain the behaviour.

> Disclaimer: I read this and this is the first thing that came to mind. I have not tested this in any way.